# Boost.Function with a custom allocator

Tags: c++, function, boost, allocator

I've done preliminary search on stackoverflow and google, and didn't find any specific lead on this, so I am going to ask it here:

Does anyone has the experienece of using boost::function with a custom allocator?

I need it because I am using functions generated from bind, and after a certain size (dependent on what params you bind), boost::function will start allocating on the heap.

I have to use boost/pool_alloc. `boost::fast_pool_allocator<>` or `boost::pool_allocator<>` to be specific. The receiving function signature is simple, which is just `function<void()>`, but I may generate this function from various binding sites, with all the possible params to bind...

Then how do I know what signature to write for the pool_alloc? e.g.:

`function<void()> f_with_alloc(bind(...), pool_allocator<????>() );`

What do I write there? It's not clear on the boost.function documentation.

Uh, some of the template code doesn't work well with stackoverflow's editor... and the editor won't let me edit again. :(

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, it doesn't matter. The class will internally rebind your allocator to the type it needs anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use `function::assign()` member function with allocator in function template.

```
template <class F, class G>
void assign(F& f, G g)
{
  f.assign(g, pool_allocator<G>());
}

boost::function<void()> f;
assign(f, bind(...));
```